# CodeIgniter's Sparks package management alternative for Zend Framework and Yii?

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, yii, package

Is there an alternative to CodeIgniter's Sparks package management in ZF and Yii?

*Sparks is a package management system for Codeigniter that will allow you install high-quality libraries into your applications instantly.* 
-> from http://getsparks.org/

Is there something similar for Zend Framework? Or Yii?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any? thanks in advance.

Comment: provide links to CI Sparks and maybe explain a bit about what it is.

Comment: Sparks is a package management system for Codeigniter that will allow you install high-quality libraries into your applications instantly. http://getsparks.org/

Comment: I meant edit your question by adding more information. The better the information you provide, the less down votes you will get, and the better the answer will be. Think about it in a different way: assume none of us knows, will never know, and don't want to know , what sparks ci is. Now explain what kind of solution you're looking for.

Comment: I have updated my question as you suggested. I hope it is now better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a package management tool for Yii yet.

You may find a list of extensions here: http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/

Most of them have installation instructions which most of the time involve just extracting the contents to the extensions/ or components/ folder.

Comment: Any plan to do it? I am just curious, because Yii seems to be on the rise.

Comment: I don't yet know of any plans but it seems like a fun project to work on! ;)